# Store lambda function in variable?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

As we know, In java-8 we can store function/method in variable. by using following way.

```
    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface MyInterface {

      public string getValue(int val1, int val2);

    }


    public class MyClass {

    static String someFun(int val1, int val2) {
       return ""+(val1+val2)

    }

     static BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String> testParamFun = (a,b) -> ""+(a+b);

    public static void main(String[] args){

       MyInterface intr = MyClass::someFun;
       System.out.println(int.getValue(2,4)); // outpur will be "6" 

       /* i want this, but it give me compile time error? 
         I want to store that function in variable like i was doing in above case. */

   MyInterface inter = MyClass::testParamFun;
   System.out.println(inter.getValue(4,5)); // it gives me error.
   // then i tried this
   System.out.println(inter.apply(4,5)); // i got error again. 


    }

    }
```

My question is, how can I store `BiDirection` in variable type `MyInterface`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your end goal here. Could you clarify a bit?

Comment: If you're going to post demonstration code, could it be working demonstration code?

Comment: i edited my question.

Comment: You cannot name your variable as `int`.

Comment: yes - its just spell mistake.

Comment: Your code contains lots of spell mistakes. Maybe your problem disappears once you fix all these errors first?

Comment: Agree to @Holger. This will run fine when you fix typos.

Comment: Although i poor spelled . but it's not a typing issue my friends :) I got an answer.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refer to the `BiFunction`'s method:

```
MyInterface int_ = MyClass.testParamFun::apply;
```